# How to create element with attribute in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a `audio` tag in javascript.

I have the following

```
  this.audioElement = createElement('audio', {className:'audio', src:'test.mp3', type:'audio/mpeg'});
```

The audio tag I want to appear in html

```
<audio controls src='test.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>
```

I am not sure how to create `controls` attribute in js. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

got it now.

```
 this.audioElement = createElement('audio', {className:'audio-asset', src:'test.mp3'});
 this.audioElement.setAttribute('controls',true);
```

Answer (score 3):

For that to work you would need a helper function `createElement` that works somewhat like this:

```
var createElement = function(type, props) {
    var $e = document.createElement(type);

    for (var prop in props) {
        $e.setAttribute(prop, props[prop]);
    }

    return $e;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
this.audioElement = createElement('audio', {className:'audio', src:'test.mp3', type:'audio/mpeg', controls: true});
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers above didn't seem to work for me. Here's what I did:

```
var audioElement;
audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('controls', true);
audioElement.setAttribute('class', 'audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'test.mp3');
audioElement.setAttribute('type', 'audio/mpeg');
```

then appended `audioElement` to the body :

```
document.body.appendChild(audioElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

//your own code for setting the attributes you have already set

audioElement.controls=true;
```

for boolean attributes like `multiple` and `disabled` just set them to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @megawac and James's answers, I think the cleanest way to do this for multiple attributes on [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_object_assign) is probably using Object.assign:

```
const colInput = document.createElement('input');
Object.assign(colInput,{
    type: 'number',
    min: 1,
    value: this.config.cols,
    onchange: this.updateSetting
});
```

Still not all in one function call, but readable and less verbose than some of the older answers here.

Comment: It's not the same as `setAttribute` though, try setting data-attributes and attributes absent form spec to see what I mean

Answer (score -1):

I'm familiar with doing this with jQuery.  I wouldn't know exactly how to do it without jQuery.

```
var $el = $('<audio>', {
    class: 'audio',
    src: 'test.mp3',
    type: 'audio/mpeg',
    controls: 'controls goes here'
});
var html = $el[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: I need to have controls attribute. your codes don't have it. +1 though.

Comment: This is jQuery.. do you have an answer with plain JavaScript?

Answer (score -2):

Enable controls

HTML

```
<button onclick="enableControls()" type="button">Enable controls</button>
<button onclick="disableControls()" type="button">Disable controls</button>
<button onclick="checkControls()" type="button">Check controls status</button>
```

JS

```
<script>
myVid=document.getElementById("audio1");
function enableControls()
  { 
  myVid.controls=true;
  myVid.load();
  } 
function disableControls()
  { 
  myVid.controls=false;
  myVid.load();
  } 
function checkControls()
  { 
  alert(myVid.controls);
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with the question.

Comment: @putvande what with the downvote? Op is asking "I am not sure how to create controls attribute in js. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!
"

Comment: Controls attribute is an attribute you add to the tag `<audio>`, so something like `<audio controls="controls">`.